# ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred on CentOS 7

Tags: oracle, centos

I am configuring a server in CentOS 7 to connect to an Oracle database within the same network. IP ORACLE = 192.167.10.100 IP SERVER = 192.167.15.123

I have installed the Instant Client Package: Basic, SDK and SQL * Plus. [Download link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)

Then set the environment variables:

ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64

PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib

TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

When entering with the SQL * Plus through the implicit connection string: With the format.

> sqlplus username/password@host:port/sid

```
sqlplus testuser/orcltiger@192.167.10.100:1521/testdb
```

I get the error: **ORA-12170: TNS: the connection timeout occurred**

I have been able to connect with the same credentials from a Windows PC with Oracle SQL Developer but from CentOS I get an error:

Someone to help me find the solution, please.

Comment: I have to ask, just because, you can PING 192.167.10.100?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes the PING successful and 0% packet loss

Comment: Sounds like maybe a firewall is blocking 1521somewhere between the client and server (but not between the PC and the server)?

Comment: Between PC and the Oracle server,  used an VPN for conection. My dba explained what in inner network not need the VPN because CentOS and Oracle they are in the same network.

Comment: @AlexPoole  How I check is the firewall problem?

Comment: @AndresFelipePolo https://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port

Comment: @thatjeffsmith  nmap -p 1521 192.167.10.100
Response:
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-11 12:42 -05
Nmap scan report for 192.167.10.100
Host is up (0.00052s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
1521/tcp filtered oracle

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.89 seconds